# How to create id one after another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

Here is the task. I have MySQL with 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'James');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Charles');
```

I want to add data to table `tasks`. I want `task_id` to go one after another
for every `user_id`. Something like this:

```
mysql> select * from tasks;
+---------+---------+-------------+
| user_id | task_id | description |
+---------+---------+-------------+
|       1 |       1 | aa          |
|       1 |       2 | bb          |
|       1 |       3 | cc          |
|       2 |       1 | aaa         |
|       2 |       2 | bbb         |
|       1 |       4 | dd          |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can always find the last line with required user_id and manually increment it, by adding `$value+1` into `task_id` field